# Multiple date ranges in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

i have query that gets values depends on date ranges like:

```
Where (CDATE(TR_DATE) >= ('03/06/2014') and CDATE(TR_DATE) <= ('13/06/2014'))
```

the problem is Access will Ignore the first condition(s) and only execute the last one....
any advise...

Comment: Is 3/6 the 3rd of June? Access interprets dates using the American system, so 3/6 would translate to the 6th of March.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access Database Engine will ***always*** interpret ambiguous `#xx/yy/zzzz#` date literals as `mm/dd/yyyy` regardless of the Regional Settings specified in Windows. Therefore, `#03/06/2014#` will ***always*** be interpreted as `March 6, 2014`. On the other hand, `#13/06/2014#` is not ambiguous because there is no 13th month, so it will be interpreted as `June 13, 2014`.

The solution is to either

1. always use `#mm/dd/yyyy#`, or even better,
2. always use the unambiguous `#yyyy/mm/dd#` format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will completely solve your problem but dates in Access should be surrounded by `#` instead of `'`:

```
WHERE CDATE(TR_DATE) >= #03/06/2014# AND CDATE(TR_DATE) <= #13/06/2014#
```

Or:

```
WHERE Format(TR_DATE, "dd/mm/yyyy") >= Format(#03/06/2014#, "dd/mm/yyyy") 
  AND Format(TR_DATE, "dd/mm/yyyy") <= Format(#13/06/2014#, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: it will only get all the values that less than 13/06/2014

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Where TR_DATE Between #06/03/2014# And #06/13/2014#
```

or

```
Where TR_DATE Between #2014-06-03# And #2014-06-13#
```

which is the more universally accepted format.